# R xgboost, problems with gamma regression

Tags: r, xgboost

I am playing around with xgboost, with some financial data and wanted to try out gamma regression as the objective.

```
cvs <- xgb.cv(data = sparse_matrix, label = target, nfold = 10, nthread = 4, nround = 16, objective = "reg:gamma", metrics = list("mae"))
```

But this seems to take much longer than using linear regression as objective.

And also throws a lot of the following warning:

```
In foldVector[which(y == dimnames(numInClass)$y[i])] <- sample(seqVector) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

This warning is repeated about 50 times.

What is going on? am i not supposed to use reg:gamma as the objective, since reg:linear is working just fine, i was just playing around and simply wanted to try various objectives

Can anyone please point out why these warnings happen?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a bit late, but it might help others. I had the same issue with a `reg:logistic` objective, and the way I solved it is by setting `stratified=FALSE` in `xgb.cv`

As per the xgboost documentation, *stratified* is a *boolean indicating whether sampling of folds should be stratified by the values of outcome labels.*

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if i am late on this, but i faced a similar issue. The issue really there is two different versions of XGBoost. One which runs with R 3.3.2 and the other is R 3.4.3
So the XGBoost package that is compatible with R 3.4.3 has the feature "reg:gamma" in it. 
I installed R 3.4.3 version and it works fine now.